# Renaming text files by reading last word of 2nd line

Tags: batch-file

I have a large number of text files.

I need a batch script that reads each file, and renames it to the last word of second line.

The last word of 2nd line of these text files is unique within the given set of files.

Comment: show what have you try so far and let us know what problem your are having

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
 SET "found="
 FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%b IN ('type "%sourcedir%\%%a"') DO IF NOT DEFINED found (
  SET "found=%%b"
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "found=!found:"=!"
  SET "found=!found: =.!"
  FOR /f %%c IN ("!found!") DO SET "found=%%~xc"
  ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!found:~1!.txt"
  ENDLOCAL 
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.